# Determining SQL MERGE statement result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, merge

Is there a way to determine whether a record was matched or not (whether the record was inserted or updated) after calling MERGE?

Ideally I'd like to output it to a parameter.

Edit:
I've got the merge statement outputting what happened in my management studio using the following statement:
Say I had the following merge statement:

```
MERGE INTO TestTable as target
USING ( select '00D81CB4EA0842EF9E158BB8FEC48A1E' )
AS source (Guid)
ON ( target.Guid = source.Guid ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Test_Column = NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Guid, Test_Column) VALUES ('00D81CB4EA0842EF9E158BB8FEC48A1E', NULL)
OUTPUT $action;
```

I'm trying to use a parameter to get the '$action' output.

Comment: I can't test this but are you using it in a manner guaranteed to only ever affect one row? If so does `OUTPUT @SomeVariable = $action";` work?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion Martin.

I was not clear enough in that I am using the .NET calls to do this. My apologies.

I did figure out that I can call:

    DbCommand command;
    ...
    DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()

and look through the resulting table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you could do is create a temporary table (or a table variable) and send your output there - add some meaningful fields to your OUTPUT clause to make it clear what row was 
affected by what action:

```
DECLARE @OutputTable TABLE (Guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, Action VARCHAR(100))

MERGE INTO TestTable as target
USING ( select '00D81CB4EA0842EF9E158BB8FEC48A1E' )
AS source (Guid)
ON ( target.Guid = source.Guid ) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET Test_Column = NULL
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (Guid, Test_Column) VALUES ('00D81CB4EA0842EF9E158BB8FEC48A1E', NULL)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Guid, $action INTO @OutputTable

SELECT
   Guid, Action
FROM
   @OutputTable
```

**UPDATE:** ah, okay, so you want to call this from .NET ! Well, in that case, just call it using the `.ExecuteReader()` method on your `SqlCommand` object - the stuff you're outputting using `OUTPUT...` will be returned to the .NET caller as a result set - you can loop through that:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mergeStmt, connection))
{
   connection.Open();

   using(SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while(rdr.Read())
      {
         var outputAction = rdr.GetValue(0);
      }

      rdr.Close();
   }
   connection.Close();
}
```

You should get back the resulting "$action" from that data reader.

Comment: thanks!

so there is no way to use SqlCommand.Parameters to get the $action then?

Comment: additionally, using ExecuteScalar if you know you're only going to get one row modified is prefered

Comment: @petejamd: actually, ExecuteScalar should be used only when you get one row *and* one column back! Just a single result that is. And no - the $action cannot be accessed through the SqlCommand.Parameters collection - it's neither an input nor an output parameter, but part of a result set.